# How can remove time from Date string

Tags: javascript

```
var x = new Date();
myVar = x.toString();
document.write(myVar);
// Sat Feb 14 2015 14:20:58 GMT+0100 (CET)
```

I want to remove the time <<14:20:58 GMT+0100 (CET)>>

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 12):

Try ...

```
var x = new Date()
var myVar = x.toDateString();
```

This will only provide the date ...

Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toDateString