# How to get certain part of Date in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Say I have the following code:

```
const d = new Date('2020-06-09T16:56:43.333214Z')
console.log(d)
```

The output of the console.log is `Tue Jun 09 2020 12:56:43 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)`
How would I make the output equal to just `Tue Jun 09 2020`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can remove time from Date string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28516176/how-can-remove-time-from-date-string)

Comment: change second line to: console.log(d.toString().substring(0, 15));